# How to set value of input to character?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core, razor-pages

How can I set the value of an input to `&#8205;` I am using razor pages so this is a .cshtml file.

If I try this:

```
<input asp-for="Title" value="&#8205;" />
```

It shows up as `&#8205;`

Comment: Hi @Daniel Veinberg, you can also use `<input asp-for="Title" value="@System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode("&#8205;")" />`. Besides, your `&#8205;` here does not represent any value when you decode it. You can have a try other character like:`&#8364;`.

Answer (score 0):

Razor pages *html encode* the values, which is why you see that.

You can either:

1. Include/paste the actual unicode character (which be hard for this
   value)
2. Change to:

```
<input asp-for="Title" value="@((char)8205)" />
```

This will include the char.

I suggest you store that character in a variable, which makes it easier.